# angularjs + spring boot + spring security partial secured application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I've started to develop a little single page application. It's a typical online Shop. I need the user to login only for the payment process so the rest of the application is accessible for every visitor.

I'm using AngularJS with routing for the frontend, Spring Boot with Spring Data and Spring Security for the backend.

Now to have some pages Secured I "tricked" Angular:

```
$routeProvider
[...]
.when("/admin/addproduct", {
    templateUrl: "/admin/addproductform",
    controller: ""
})
[...]
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: "/"
});
```

into run over my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);



  @RequestMapping(value="/admin/addproductform", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String addProductForm(){
      return "/templates/admin/admin_add_product.html";
  }
}
```

this is my Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/templates/login.html").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and()
    .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
    .csrf()
    .disable();
//      had to disable csrf, because it screwed with the file upload
//      .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
}

//  private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
//    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
//    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
//    return repository;
//  }

}
```

Now my question, is this approach generally wrong? Is it even possible to just secure some pages with AngularJs and Spring Security?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So your strategy is to secure access to the templates used in Angular? That could work, but your controller URL doesn't match the template URL, so I am confused, and you would need some client-side code to deal with the unauthorized cases. Did you see this blog series: https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application (your CSRF problem is probably solved in Part II)?

Comment: You're right, that solves the issue why it's not working. `code .when("/admin/addproduct", {
   templateUrl: "/admin/addproductform",
   controller: ""
  }) `, I'll edit the question.

Comment: But the actual question I have here is if this is a somewhat good implementation. I'm new with AngularJS but have worked with Spring MVC. The blog series is the one thing I really found helpful, but it covers a fully secured page not a partial one (correct me if I'm wrong). The csrf issue is not really relevant right now, because I tend to change how the fileupload works anyway. Other than that I use the csrf implementation described in the blog series

Comment: I have another blog in the pipeline about access decisions. Basically I believe you have little choice but to implement some of the logic in he client, but that doesn't mean you don't need protection in the server as well.